# How to fix react native console.log memory leak

Tags: react-native, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using `twilio-chat` to make a chat app in react native.
After I create client, I tried to console.log the client entity, but then I saw the performance monitor in expo showed the memory used is increasing and the UI freezed, then the app crashed.

How do I fix it? Or do you think it is a `twilio-chat` library bug?

Edit:
I have found the culprit, its because of circular reference in the twilio-chat objects, logging these objects will in react native will cause memory leak.

My workaround is to stringify the objects, and hope one day they fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same issue, but it was because I have stored client / channel object in reducer. I think it could be close. Please check when and where you throw / use this objects.

Comment: if you can add example that would be helpful.